# Action delegate dependency resolution using Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a class with a constructor that looks like this:

```
public TimedWorker(int timerInterval, Action execute, ILogger logger)
```

I am using the Castle Windsor fluent configuration and whilst the config below works, I am concerned about the way I am resolving Action. Is there a better way so that I am not always resolving the action delegate to the same thing?

```
Component
  .For<IWorker>()
  .ImplementedBy<TimedWorker>()
  .DependsOn(new { timerInterval = TimerInterval })
  .LifeStyle.Transient,

Component.For<Action>()
  .Instance(() => Resolve<SomeService>().SomeMethod())
  .LifeStyle.Transient,

Component.For<ILogger>()
  .ImplementedBy<TraceLogProvider>()
  .LifeStyle.Singleton
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the Action anywhere else you could use DynamicParameters:

```
Component
  .For<IWorker>()
  .ImplementedBy<TimedWorker>()
  .DynamicParameters((kernel, parameters) => {
    parameters["timerInterval"] = TimerInterval;
    parameters["execute"] = new Action(kernel.Resolve<SomeService>().SomeMethod);
  })
  .LifeStyle.Transient, ...
```

Comment: Fluent API registration docs: http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE]**

Ok, in this case Mauricio's solution is the best way to go.

---

There's nothing wrong with the approach.
If you want more flexibility than `.Instance` gives you, use `.UsingFactoryMethod`.

What is exactly your concern here?

Comment: My main concern is that my code assumes that I only have to resolve one Action and in the future, should another component require a different Action dependency, my code will no longer work.

Comment: Perhaps if you gave it a name and use service overrides it would be more viable? You can also try this idea: http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/09/convention-based-dependency-injection-with-castle-microkernelwindsor.aspx instead of service overrides, although be sure to limit your resolver to only Action delegates